# How to create an animation with a filled 'span?

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I've created an animated plot of a wavefunction, psi:

```
def psi(x, t):
    real = 0.4*np.cos(0.4*x - 0.08*t) + 0.6*np.cos(0.6*x - 0.18*t)
    imag = 0.4*np.sin(0.4*x - 0.08*t) + 0.6*np.sin(0.6*x - 0.18*t)
    square = real**2 + imag**2
return real, imag, square
```

I've then animated it successfully, however on adding the `axvspan` fill I've encountered an issue:

```
x = np.linspace(-10, 1000, 10000)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2,1)

line1, = ax1.plot([], [])
line2, = ax1.plot([], [])
line3, = ax2.plot([], [])
line = [line1, line2, line3]

def animate(i):
    
    y1, y2, y3 = psi(x, t=i/2)
    
    line1.set_data(x, y1)
    line2.set_data(x, y2)
    line3.set_data(x, y3)
    
    
    spline = UnivariateSpline(x, y3-max(y3)/2, s=0)
    r1, r2 = spline.roots()
    ax2.axvspan(r1, r2, facecolor='b', alpha=0.5)
    
    plt.legend(['Max Probability = %1.3f' % (max(y3))])
    return line,

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=600, interval = 100, blit=False, repeat=False)
```

It starts like [image: this]

and it ends like [image: this].

Every iteration of the animation function, the fill increases across the page having started off as filling half the graph (I'd include a gif but at the moment that's a struggle I'm having with anaconda). I'm working under the assumption this is because the axes don't clear properly, however with the blit=false I assumed this wouldn't be a problem?

As asked for - the full `psi` function is detailed below:

```
n = 15

amp_scale = np.linspace(0, 0.8, n)
amp_init = norm.pdf(amp_scale, 0.4, 0.2)

#normalise wavefunction to prob=1
amp = []

for i in range(n):
    amp_val = amp_init[i]/sum(amp_init)
    amp.append(amp_val)

k = np.linspace(1.4, 2.6, n)


def psi (x, t=1, n=1, a = 1, k = 1, m = 1):
    
    psi_real = 0
    psi_imag = 0

    for i in range(n):
        a_val = a[i]
        k_val = k[i]
        w = (k_val**2)/(2*m)
        psi_real+=a_val*np.cos(k_val*x - w*t)
        psi_imag+=a_val*np.sin(k_val*x - w*t)
    
    psi_squared = psi_real**2 + psi_imag**2
    
    return psi_real, psi_imag, psi_squared
```

Comment: I'm still wondering how your real `psi` function looks like.

Comment: @JohanC I've now added the function att he end of the question, sorry it didn't quite make sense in the first instance!

Comment: also this answer is excellent, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current code, a new `axvspan()` is continually added, never removed.  You could explicitly remove the old span inside `animate()`. Or, similarly to what happens to the lines, update the position. A span is internally represented as a polygon, of which the coordinates can be set via `.set_xy()`.

The function `psi` in the post doesn't seem to be the same as the function that generated the example plots. This also made that I couldn't get to work to calculate the spline and the roots.  I replaced them by some simpler positions to show how the span can be updated during the animation.

The code also adds explicit x and y limits, as they weren't set in the question's code.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline

def psi(x, t):
    # the function from the question is adapted to more resemble the plot
    real = (0.4 * np.cos(0.4 * x - 0.08 * t) + 0.6 * np.cos(0.6 * x - 0.18 * t)) * np.exp(- (x - t) ** 2 / 5000)
    imag = (0.4 * np.sin(0.4 * x - 0.08 * t) + 0.6 * np.sin(0.6 * x - 0.18 * t)) * np.exp(- (x - t) ** 2 / 5000)
    square = real ** 2 + imag ** 2
    return real, imag, square

x = np.linspace(-10, 1000, 10000)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, sharex=True)

line1, = ax1.plot([], [])
line2, = ax1.plot([], [])
line3, = ax2.plot([], [])
line = [line1, line2, line3]

span1 = ax2.axvspan(0, 0, facecolor='b', alpha=0.2)
ax1.set_xlim(x[0], x[-1]/2)
ax1.set_ylim(-1, 1)
ax2.set_ylim(0, 1.1)

def animate(i):
    y1, y2, y3 = psi(x, t=i / 2)

    line1.set_data(x, y1)
    line2.set_data(x, y2)
    line3.set_data(x, y3)

    # this didn't work for me, spline.roots() gave me a long array of values
    spline = UnivariateSpline(x, y3 - max(y3) / 2, s=0)
    r1, r2 = spline.roots()[[0, -1]] # [[0, -1]] takes the first and the last
    # r1, r2 = i - 50, i + 50
    span1.set_xy([[r1, 0], [r1, 1], [r2, 1], [r2, 0], [r1, 0]])

    plt.legend(['Max Probability = %1.3f' % (max(y3))])
    return line, span1, ax2.legend_,

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=600, interval=100, blit=False, repeat=False)

plt.plot()
```

The resulting end frame looks like (note that a slightly different function is used):
[image: end frame]